# matrix norm formulas for operators between $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $A=(a_{i,j}):\ell_\infty\to\ell_1$ and $B=(b_{i,j}):\ell_1\to\ell_\infty$ be linear operators.  We can define their operator/matrix norms as follows:
$$
\|A\|_{\infty,1}
=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left|\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{i,j}x_j \right|:\sup|x_j|\leq 1\right\}
$$
and
$$
\|B\|_{1,\infty}
=\sup\left\{\sup\left|\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_{i,j}x_j\right|:\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j|\leq 1\right\}
$$
Are there any "nicer" formulas for these norms which can be written only in terms of $(a_{i,j})$ and $(b_{i,j})$, without reference to arbitrary vectors $(x_j)$?  I vaguely remember that there are such formulas, but I can't seem to find them today.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $|x_j|\leq 1$, $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{i,j}x_j \right|\le\sum_{j=1}^\infty|a_{i,j}|$$ with equality when $x_j=\mathrm{sgn}(a_{i,j})$.